# Regarding wso2 Api Publisher

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I have exposed a service in my local host on jboss `http://10.19.6.115:8080/jboss-helloworld-rs`. When I set this url as the http end point in publisher and publish this API from a different machine. the url which is shown in the store is the ip address of the machine where the publisher is hosted. `http://10.19.6.5:8280/jboss-helloworld-rs` and the port is changed to `8280`. My question is how and why does the apistore show a different endpoint address that which was provided in publisher.

I am getting started with wso2 any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 API Manager has a gateway component that sends incoming requests to the backend. This gateway component will running in your machine the same as publisher running because it seems like you have not created cluster using API Manager. So the store will show the URLs of the gateway components.

The main thing is no point of showing actual backend in store because the purpose here is hiding the actual backend and sending the incoming requests to the backend via API Manager. Otherwise the features in API Manager is not useful. For more information refer [1]

[1]https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM180/Quick+Start+Guide